# Python Pandas left join on Index not column index not column name

Tags: python, pandas

Im new to Python Pandas, and was wondering if there was a way to join left two .csv files based on the column index number, at the moment i have this.

```
#Obtaining first csv files
neutral = pd.read_csv('neutral.csv')
meter = pd.read_csv('meter.csv')
#Left joins on MSN them to create merged Dataframe
merged = pd.merge(ph_neutral, meter,
                   on='MSN',
                   how='left')
```

but instead of joining on 'MSN' i want to join on the column index 1

Comment: replace `on='MSN'` with `left_on=ph_neutral.columns[1], right_on=meter.columns[1]`.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Try to run something like this: ph_neutral.merge(meter, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')